# Can java run a compiled scala code?

Tags: java, scala

Can command `java` run a compiled scala code? If so, why do we have an exclusive command `scala`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can run byte code generated by Scala if you include all necessary runtime libs for Scala (scala-library.jar, scala-swing.jar ...) in the classpath. The scala command does this automatically, and supports Scala specific command line arguments.

Comment: `java -cp ./scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar:./scala-library-2.11.8.jar  HelloWorld` This did not work for me.

Comment: my hello world program is just this `object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks. What is "The scala command"? Is `scala` command the compiler?

Comment: @Tim `scala` is for running compiled code, the Scala compiler would be `scalac`

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it can. Scala is compiled down to Java bytecode. But remember that it depends on the Scala runtime classes, so you need to still have Scala's jar files on the classpath.

> If so, why do we have an exclusive command scala?

Convenience wrapper.

Comment: scala is an interpreter, while scalac is a compiler.. its not only for convenience but also a different technique.

Comment: You could start the compiler, too--it's just another class that needs to be run (scala.tools.nsc.Main, with appropriate arguments).  But convenience is convenient, so why do it the hard way?

Answer (score 6):

> Scala is designed to integrate easily
>   with applications that run on modern
>   virtual machines, primarily the Java
>   virtual machine (JVM). The main Scala
>   compiler, scalac, generates Java class
>   files that can be run on the JVM.
>   -> http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html

As long as you have installed the scala runtime you should be fine: compile classes with `scalac` and run them with `java`.

Answer (score 4):

Just want to add my own answer as additional value for the future readers:

> scala, if run without parameter, will run an interactive shell
>
> scala, if run with a text file name as parameter, will regard the file as a scala script

those two can't be done using java

Comment: Both of those can be done, but it is particularly annoying to do it--you have to call scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner and make sure the appropriate tools are in the classpath.  Why not just let the scala script do it for you?

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely, the `scala` command is simply a bash helper-script which summarize to the below command:

```
$cat /usr/local/Cellar/scala@2.11/2.11.12_1/libexec/bin/scala

execCommand \
  "${JAVACMD:=java}" \
  $JAVA_OPTS \
  "${java_args[@]}" \
  "${classpath_args[@]}" \
  -Dscala.home="$SCALA_HOME" \
  $OVERRIDE_USEJAVACP \
  "$EMACS_OPT" \
  $WINDOWS_OPT \
   scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  "$@"
```

There are 2 things required to run a `.class` file compiled using `scalac` ( the scala compiler) using the `java` command.

1. We need to include the `scala-library.jar` and the `location of the .class file` in the `classpath`. To find the location of `scala-library.jar`, please execute the
   below:

   `which scala /usr/local/opt/scala@2.11/bin/scala`

   In my case the `scala-*.jar` files are in :
   `/usr/local/Cellar/scala@2.11/2.11.12_1/idea/lib` on Mac
2. The location of the `Main2.class` file which is in `/training/example1/scala`.

So, to execute the program we could use the below command:

```
java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/scala@2.11/2.11.12_1/idea/lib/scala-library.jar:/training/example1/scala/ Main2
```

EDIT-1: If you are using windows, please use semicolon(;) as the separator in java classpath command.