# Using Google Caliper with Scala

Tags: scala, noclassdeffounderror, caliper

I am trying to use Caliper with Scala(2.10) in Eclipse Juno(4.2). For the start I've set up a benchmark that simply iterates a foreachloop over an array.

```
import com.google.caliper.Param
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark

class Benchmark extends SimpleBenchmark {

  @Param(Array("10", "100", "1000", "10000"))
  val length: Int = 0
  var array: Array[Int] = _

  override def setUp() {
    array = new Array(length)
  }

  def timeForeach(reps: Int) = {
    var result = 0
    array.foreach {
      result += _
    }
    result
  }
```

When I start the benchmark with:

```
object myRunner {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   Runner.main(classOf[Benchmark], args)
 }
}
```

I get these exceptions that I dont understand

```
0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Foreach, length=10}  Failed to execute java -cp C:\Users\bob\workspace\myBenchmark\bin;C:\Users\bob\workspace\caliper\caliper\target>\classes;C:\Users\bob\workspace\caliper\caliper\target\test-classes;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\1.7.1\gson-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.1\guava-11.0.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\code\java-allocation-instrumenter\java-allocation-instrumenter\2.0\java-allocation-instrumenter-2.0.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.3.1\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-analysis\3.3.1\asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-commons\3.3.1\asm-commons-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-tree\3.3.1\asm-tree-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-util\3.3.1\asm-util-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-xml\3.3.1\asm-xml-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.2\junit-3.8.2.jar com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner --warmupMillis 3000 --runMillis 1000 --measurementType TIME --marker //ZxJ/ -Dbenchmark=Foreach -Dlength=10 org.example.Benchmark
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.caliper.ScenarioSelection.getClassByName(ScenarioSelection.java:154)
    at com.google.caliper.ScenarioSelection.prepareSuite(ScenarioSelection.java:123)
    at com.google.caliper.ScenarioSelection.select(ScenarioSelection.java:83)
    at com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner.run(InProcessRunner.java:38)
    at com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner.main(InProcessRunner.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more

An exception was thrown from the benchmark code.
com.google.caliper.ConfigurationException: Failed to execute java -cp C:\Users\bob\workspace\myBenchmark\bin;C:\Users\bob\workspace\caliper\caliper\target\classes;C:\Users\bob\workspace\caliper\caliper\target\test-classes;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\1.7.1\gson-1.7.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.1\guava-11.0.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\google\code\java-allocation-instrumenter\java-allocation-instrumenter\2.0\java-allocation-instrumenter-2.0.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.3.1\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-analysis\3.3.1\asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-commons\3.3.1\asm-commons-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-tree\3.3.1\asm-tree-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-util\3.3.1\asm-util-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\asm\asm-xml\3.3.1\asm-xml-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.2\junit-3.8.2.jar com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner --warmupMillis 3000 --runMillis 1000 --measurementType TIME --marker //ZxJ/ -Dbenchmark=Foreach -Dlength=10 org.example.Benchmark
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.measure(Runner.java:309)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.runScenario(Runner.java:229)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.runOutOfProcess(Runner.java:378)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.run(Runner.java:97)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.main(Runner.java:423)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.main(Runner.java:436)
    at org.example.myRunner$.main(myRunner.scala:7)
    at org.example.myRunner.main(myRunner.scala)
```

I think I have some issues with the classpath but i am not sure.

I hope someone can help me :)

thanks in advance
Davram Bashere

Comment: It looks like scala-library.jar needs to be on the classpath

Comment: I thought so too. So I tried to include my scala library in the java buildpath of the caliper project - without any change, the result is the same :(

Comment: Adding it to the build path of Caliper is not going to solve the problem. You need to tell Caliper to add it to the classpath of the JVM instance that it forks. I've no idea how to do that, but I'm sure that it must provide some way to do so.

Comment: It didn't work because I've included the scala jar to the java buildpath by using eclipse instead of by adding a dependency to the pom.xml - just stupid

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much as though Caliper is running a new JVM and doesn't know that it needs to include the Scala libraries on the classpath.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626002/can-java-run-a-compiled-scala-code) describes how to run a Scala app with the `java` command on the command line. It should be a good starting point to solving this problem.

Comment: Caliper does start a new JVM (to insulate your benchmark from JIT, GC, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are editing scala sources in Eclipse you may still use [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/home.html) to run your code. Sbt is a great tool for managing your projects classpath in addition to providing a plugin system for providing the kinds of features like running Caliper benchmarks. I recently worked on a project where I needed just that and factored it out into an published [sbt plugin](https://github.com/softprops/cappi#readme). This may be of some help for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. The problem was as expected the stupid classpath. I have downloaded the caliper project from googlecode and added the scala dependency. Now I've build my own jar-with-dependencies and it works quite fine.

Thanks for the answeres anyway :-)

Comment: I don't understand classpath, but I have the same problem.  Can you describe your solution in more detail?

Comment: Anyway, I solved the problem:  I cloned the project and "build artifact" did not work.  I have to re-specify the "build artifact" dialog, so the dependencies are be fetched again.  After that I rebuild the jar and it's correct.