# Creating Spark application using wrong Scala version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am following the instructions here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html to create a simple application that will run on a local standalone Spark build.

In my system I have Scala 2.9.2 and sbt 0.13.7.
When I write in my `simple.sbt` the following:

`scalaVersion := "2.9.2"`

after I use `sbt package`, I get the error:
`sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.9.2;1.3.1: not found`

However, when I write in `simple.sbt`:

`scalaVersion := "2.10.4"`

sbt runs successfully and the application runs fine on Spark.

How can this happen, since I do not have scala 2.10.4 on my system?

Comment: Sbt download scala compiler in version 2.10.4 and use it.

Comment: The below post would also be helping you. I believe! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883325/scala-spark-version-compatibility

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scala is not a package, it is a library that executes on top of the Java runtime. Likewise, the Scala compiler `scalac` runs on top of a Java runtime.  The fact that you have a version of Scala installed in your "system" is a convenience, but is not in any way required.

Therefore, it is entirely possible to launch `sbt` from one version of Scala (2.9.2) but instruct it to run other commands (compilation) using an entirely different version of Scala (2.10.x) by passing the appropriate flags such as `-classpath`.

See: [Can java run a compiled scala code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626002/can-java-run-a-compiled-scala-code)

Answer (score 7):

As @noahlz said, you don't need Scala on your system as sbt will fetch it for you.

The issue you're having is that there is not `spark-core` version `1.3.1` for Scala 2.9.2.

From what I can see in Maven Central (searching for [spark-core](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|spark-core)) there are only builds of `spark-core` for Scala 2.10 and 2.11.

Therefore I would recommend you use this setup:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1"
```

If for whatever reason that doesn't work for you, use Scala 2.10.5:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1"
```