# Scala Spark java.lang.VerifyError: class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray overrides final method toBuffer.()

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I trying to run a sample scala spark program on intellij. I have created a maven project and added scala nature to the project. I'm able to run the scala hello world program, but I'm trying to run spark-scala, its throwing the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray overrides final method toBuffer.()Lscala/collection/mutable/Buffer;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
    at com.dnb.dsl.test.SparkDemo$.main(SparkDemo.scala:7)
```

Here I'm attaching the the program,

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 
    object SparkDemo { def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkDemo").setMaster("local")
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
     val input = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
     input.foreach(println) 
       } 
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <spark.version>2.0.1</spark.version>
        <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Attaching scala sdk verion configuration from intellij.
Java version used:1.8

[image: scala version from intellij]

Comment: You will need to downgrade your Scala version from 2.13 to 2.11, or better yet, use Spark 2.4.5 and Scala 2.12.

Comment: @mazaneicha throwing another exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/collection/Seq;)V

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883325/scala-spark-version-compatibility and https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/#downloading: _Spark 2.0.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x)._

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach and as @mazaneicha has suggested  downgrade your `Scala` version. Instead of Maven I would use `SBT` for `Scala`. `IntelliJ` comes fully integrated with `SBT` and `Scala`, and `SBT` is really easy to work with.

A `build.sbt` for your example would be:

```
name := "my-project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.2.0"
```

To find and download libraries for your spark projects you can use Maven repository:

[Spark Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=spark)