# Difference between running with Java & Scala

Tags: java, scala

As Scala generates bytecode that can be run on JVM, what is difference between running/executing the generated bytecode with "java MainClass" and "scala MainClass" ?

Comment: Although your question is phrased slightly differently, it [has been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3626048/396255) in the question [Can java run a compiled scala code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626002/can-java-run-a-compiled-scala-code)